# A YellowBox do React Native pode ser ignorada?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Em alguns pontos da minha aplicação, o React apresenta erros na Yellow Box, como, por exemplo:

> Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Eu sei que é possível desativá-las, mas isso pode causar algum problema no meu app? Caso eu não desative e gere o APK, isso por comprometer a aplicação de alguma forma?

Comment: Mesmo que desative não significa que vai corrigir o problema que **você** esta ignorando, que é a duplicidade de IDs na lista, ter IDs duplicadas vai causar problemas no teu programa, problemas q você nem imagina, ID é pra sempre ser unico, corrija isto e a caixa amarela vai sumir como se fosse por mágica.

Comment: O ideal é corrigir esses *warnings*, na maioria das vezes são avisos sobre coisas que podem causar problemas de desempenho, mau uso de hooks ou algo *deprecated*

Comment: poste o código, mas, já foi bem relatado porque a lista precisa ser única na interação e cada item precisa ter um `key` diferente ... post o código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os Yellow Box's do React Native são mensagens de Warning do sistema. São avisos ou informações que o RN te informa dizendo que algo pode estar com um problema, mas que não está impedindo a execução da aplicação.

Diferente dos Red Box que irão quebrar a aplicação e não permitirá que o APK seja gerado ou executado.

`Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` Neste caso por exemplo o RN está pedindo uma chave única para os itens de uma lista que não esta sendo passado. Isso não irá impedir a lista de ser renderizada, mas ocasionalmente pode trazer problemas para a aplicação, já que seria recomendado cada item da lista possuir uma chave identificadora.

Você pode gerar um APK com yellow box ou executar o aplicativo. Mas o recomendado seria tratar esses problemas.

Outra coisa sobre as Yellow Box e que você também pode utilizá-las para seus próprios logs com o comando `console.warn()`

Você pode desativar as Yellow Box's usando `console.disableYellowBox = true;`

Caso queira saber mais poder ler essa página de debug da [documentação](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging) que possui mais informações.